# Using entityframework to load data from database into DbSet<T>.Local

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, in-memory

is there anyway to load all the data within my database into my EF-DbContext?
So basically loading all the data into the memmory and then use entityframework as usual?
The things is that I will pull some data from a datasource and then store that data in an SQL-database.. later on this application of mine will simply read and query that data(No Add, Update, Delete or any other stuff that might change the data).. so my idea is basically to load all the data to the DbSet.Local and then query the local data.. would this be possible?

I have read something about a method called .Load()
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592911.aspx

However.. I dont quite get if this might be exactly what Im looking for.. or if its something else..

Any ideas?

Br,
Inx

Comment: You might want to rethink over that!! coz you want all the data to be present even when it is unused... seems a red flag to me ,moreover it will bring your startup time to an extreme low.

Comment: well basically my idea is to load the data in Application_Start and store it in a static variable (or property).. since the data is sort of "read-only" I wont have any issues with the data beeing "shared" across multiple users/visitors.

Comment: so use static data or some kind of caching (MemoryCache etc.), anything is more appropriate than long-running context used to keep data in-memory.